# datatables table.fnStandingRedraw is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to load an extension for the datatables plugin but it's always saying table.fnStandingRedraw is not a function when I've included it

shim:

```
'datatables': {
    deps: ['jquery']
},
'fnStandingRedraw': {
    deps: ['datatables']
},
```

paths:

```
'datatables': '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min',
'fnStandingRedraw': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/api/fnStandingRedraw',
```

it's this peice of code that never seem to work

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnStandingRedraw = function(oSettings) {
    if(oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide === false){
        var before = oSettings._iDisplayStart;

        oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);

        // iDisplayStart has been reset to zero - so lets change it back
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = before;
        oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
    }

    // draw the 'current' page
    oSettings.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings);
};
```

when in use I get that error:

```
table.fnStandingRedraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have the problem in the path of fnStandingRedraw.js please put the .js extension in path of fnStandingRedraw.

New Path as Below

'datatables': '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', 'fnStandingRedraw': '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/api/fnStandingRedraw.js',